# Menu horizontal responsive no funciona

Tags: html, css, html5, responsive

tengo una página montada en HostGator, en la página hay un menú horizontal y al hacerlo responsive funciona muy bien de manera local, sin embargo las subcategorías como "ISO 9001:2015" etc, no se pueden ver cuando están montadas solo de manera responsive, no sé si algo cambia cuando lo subo al host o a que se deba..
Al dar clic para que me salga el menú donde se encuentra "ISO 9001:2015" y los demás cursos me sale lo siguiente: `https://pagina.com/index.html#`, así se llama la página principal, es decir, no me dirige a ningún lado

Código HTML:

```
<nav class="menu navegacion">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Certificación de sistemas de gestión<span class="icon-down-open"></span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="ISO-9001-2015.html">ISO 9001:2015</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ISO-14001-2015.html">ISO 14001:2015</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ISO-45001-2018.html">ISO 45001:2018</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="acerca_de.html">Acerca de</a></li>
                    <li><a href="proceso_certificacion.html">Proceso de Certificación</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Código CSS:

```
/* ------------------------------------------menu--------------------------------------------*/

header {
    height: 7rem;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

#btn-menu {
    display: none;
}

header label {
    font-size: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.menu ul {
    background: #000000;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

menu a:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

menu a span {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    header {
        height: 7rem;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #FFF;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
    }
    header label {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5rem;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    .menu ul {
        display: block;
        background: #555;
    }
    .menu ul li:hover ul {
        display: none;
        position: static;
    }
    .menu a span {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
    }
    #btn-menu:checked~.menu {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    /* .menu ul ul {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }*/
    .menu ul ul a {
        padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo el problema es que los enlaces que conforman tu menú HTML no abren las páginas HTML a las que apuntas cuando lo subes a un hosting.

Es un problema con las rutas.
Si esta desarrollando en Windows, por ejemplo, no es *case-sensitive*, sin embargo los servidores suelen ser máquinas Linux, que sí lo es. Entonces un `A` es lo mismo que una `a` en el nombre de un archivo si estas en Windows, pero en un servidor, esa diferencia hace que el archivo sea uno diferente y no "enlazan".

Si tu `index.html` está en el mismo directorio que los demás ficheros HTML, la ruta debería ser: `href="./ISO-9001-2015.html"`
Esto debería funcionar si el fichero NO se llama `iso-9001-2015.html`, fíjate en las mayúsculas y minúsculas de los nombres.

Comment: No funcionan cuando están de tamaño responsive pero cuando abarcan toda la pantalla si abren las páginas HTML :(

Comment: Eso es raro. El CSS no tiene porque afectar a la navegación, a no ser que el elemento se vea en una zona diferente a donde se encuentre y no lo estés accionando... Veo que tienes *translates* seguramente estas clicando en un area que no acciona el enlace.